# how to fix the column height equal to another column height which is quite bigger in neat?

Tags: css, bourbon, neat

ive been using foundation and i am brand new to neat.
i want to know how to set the column height wqual to the **second column height or maybe minimum heignt equal to second column.**
thanks.

[image: Question Image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a CSS problem, originally this was solved by using HTML tables, that is no longer the best practice.

CSS3 gives you a `display:table` that can be used on the container and `display:table-cell` that can be used on the columns.

There are other more complicated methods of doing this for old browsers, but `display:table` has pretty good browser support (IE8+).